# When are daycounts needed for the floating leg of a swap?

Tags: swaps, floating-rate, daycounting

For the fixed leg, the daycount is needed since the PV is $\sum_t N\delta_{t}r DF_t$ where $\delta_t$ is the daycount accrual factor at time $t$.

However for the floating leg it looks like $\sum_t N \delta_t F_t DF_t$ where $F_t = (P(t-1)/P(t) - 1)/\delta_t$. Here the daycounts cancel out, so when is the daycount accrual factor $\delta_t$ needed for the floating leg?

Comment: Only true with your exact form of $F_t$. Is this true for all other cases; period rate is calculated with RFR average rate, or adding in spread compounding, or using lookback, or using lockout, or the discount curve is not derived from the same index (e.,g. ESTR and Euribor)? <Spoiler>. No.

Comment: "period rate is calculated with RFR average rate"? what is that? do you mean OIS swaps? In that case, $F_t$ has the same form as per risk-neutral evaluation, as least until we know a partial fixing in the middle of a period.
"the discount curve is not derived from the same index" and that changes what?

Answer (score 3):

You are reliant on the formula for the rate of the floating period being as stated:

$$
F_t = \left ( \frac{P(t-1)}{P(t)} - 1 \right ) \frac{1}{\delta_t}
$$
and the period DCF $\delta_t$ being equal. This is a special case and is only true sometimes.

Examples of when it is not true:

1. Take an IMM swap period between Wed 20th March 2024 and Wed 19th June 2024, versus 3M Euribor. The DCF for the accrual period on the swap, $\delta_p$ is between those dates. The DCF for 3M Euribor rate, $\delta_t$, runs between 20th March and 20th June. $\delta_p \ne \delta_t$
2. Suppose that the floating rate has a spread applied with a simple compounding method then $$
   F_t = \left ( \frac{P(t-1)}{P(t)} - 1 \right ) \frac{1}{\delta_t} + z
   $$
   In this case one observes that the $\delta_t$ do not cancel due the presence of the spread.
3. Suppose you defined a rare kind of customised leg where the day count applied to the period did not align with the convention for the underlying index. Then the two '$\delta_t$' would again not be the same.

Comment: 3) What do you mean by "convention for the underlying index"? There is no convention. We just have $P(t)$, a discount factor for each date $t$. The $t$s are e.g. 20th Match 2024 and 20th June 2024. There is no convention needed here. There is only one DCF and that is $\delta_t$, which is computed based on the day-count convention for the period of your swap. What other $\delta_t$ is there?

Comment: SOFR or ESTR are index rates that use Act360 convention. Therefore calculating a compounded SOFR rate from a curve (without spread) consists of taking fraction of  start DF and end DF minus one and dividing by the DCF measured between start and end with the Act360 convention. Now suppose your floating period is designed to produce a payment settling to that rate with another convention, e.g. ActActICMA, or 30e360? This is not common but is easily programmed into most Leg constructors.